What type of Victoria metrics for executions with very small time period
to summarize in brief words:
I have a 'task engine' with channel where tasks/functions are sent for processing. The task Engine is initialized with a cache of 5 minutes time limit. Every time, a task is submitted to the channel, I increment the value in cache and once the execution is done, I decrement the value.
Now the 'functions' being sent to this task engine are processed very quickly, some in let's say just a matter of few seconds. I send the metric call to the endpoint every 30 seconds.
I want to capture the number of in-flight functions/tasks in the Task Engine. Since the metric call to endpoint is every 30 seconds, the accurate number of tasks is not captured as the actual functions might all be done by the time the call is made and the value is 0. I implemented a cache to store all the in-flight tasks for 5 min because I cannot change the time-period of the metric call but I'm not sure if that's the best option.
Does anyone have a better idea of how in this scenario I could get the number of in-flight tasks or what's the closest way of getting this metric?

[1/2] Implement a complex metric which works like this: it measures the number of in-flight tasks each, say, 5 seconds and stores the measurements in an array or list (your question is not really about Go, so I'm also speaking of abstract containers here) of some size (see below); when a new measurement is about to be added, it should "push out" the oldest one. Once the endpoint is contacted to get the number of in-flight tasks, you take N last measurements (or all measurements), average them and return the result.

[2/2] As you can see, your endpoint won't provide the exact measurement but it's not really possible to implement except by letting the endpoint-handling code to directly inspect the number of in-flight requests. The latter is pretty simple to maintain — say by using an atomic counter which is incremented by 1 when spawning a new job and decremented when it's done.

Also note that if what you're after collecting sort-of precise history of the samples of in-flight requests, you need to implement a metric which returns an array of measurements each time it's read. Like, say, if you read your metric once in 30s, you could return 6 measurements over 5s intervals or 10 measurements of 3s or 30 measurements of 1s—you get the idea. Of course, you'd need complex processing on the receiving end.
